# Flink dynamic scaling 1.5

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep, flink-sql

This is regarding dynamic rescaling in Flink 1.5

I am using Yarn for running Flink jobs. I start these jobs with a static resource.  Is there any option to scale out these job by itself in specific conditions like if there's a memory issues.

[In Flink 1.5 release notes](https://flink.apache.org/news/2018/05/25/release-1.5.0.html#release-notes) -

`Applications can be rescaled without manually triggering a savepoint. Under 
the hood, Flink will still take a savepoint, stop the application, and 
rescale it to the new parallelism.`

This means that I will have to monitor my jobs memory and will have to trigger rescale manually. Is these any workaround to handle this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 1.5 Flink doesn't support what you want. The process for rescaling a job is:

1. Start a job with parallelism `initialParallelism` and maxParallelism `maxParallelism`.
2. Manually stop it.
3. Rerun it with `initialParallelism <= parallelism <= maxParallelism`.

Answer (score 4):

You would still need to monitor your application, but the rescaling can be done easily by running:

```
./bin/flink modify -p <NEW-PARALLELISM>
```